# Difference amplifier show fixed voltage on its output

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

I'm using a difference amplifier as shown on [this page](http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/buildingblocks/rtd-temperature-sensing):

[image: Schematic]

I double checked my resistors values, I have RA=10k and RB=56k. I'm using a 5V reference and a 0V ground.

On the actual board, I have V1=0.1V to V1=0.4V (this is adjustable) and V2=0.5V. However the output is always Vout=3.85V, even when I change the V1 voltage.

I double checked the resistors and LM324 pins, and see nothing wrong.

I also measured V+=V-=0.684 when V1=0.4V and V+=V-=0.542 when V1=0.1V

How could I determine what is the cause of the problem? Do you have any idea at what the problem could be?

Comment: I wouldn`t rely too much on voltage measurements at the inpuit pins. On the other hand - do you provide the input voltages (I assume DC, correct?) at a sufficiently small source resistance ?

Comment: One obvious problem is that you don't have any power connected to the opamp, and of course no bypass cap.  Also, put part values in the schematic where it makes the circuit easier to see.  No, I'm not going to spend a lot of time flipping my eyes back and forth between the text and the schematic.

Comment: What do you mean by V+ and V-? Are those your opamp supply pins? Have you connected them to anything? You write about a 5V reference - where is that in your circuit diagram ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm so the opamp supply pins are +5 and ground?
The 3.85 V output suggests the opamp is hitting the positive rail.

V(+) should always be 0.5V * 56k/66k. 
Check all the pins and such and make sure you haven't mixed up the inputs.
Then try a new opamp maybe you let the magic smoke out of this one and didn't see it. :^)

Comment: The issue was that the re was a short-circuit between a few tracks (I think it was between V+ and V-). I don't know why I didn't find it before. Now, I'll always double and triple-check.